# Grab results from mysql and apply each result to variable and finally output

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

So what I'm trying to do is:
Run this query:`SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet =1` which outputs two results:[image: img1]

I want to append the two results to the `$result` var and interiate through the results (being 2 - as shown in the picture) as `$r`, then output the parts of `$r` thus being

```
# Source of Article Info-->
            $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

    # Actual News Article Info -->
            $title=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $desc=$newsStory[$i]->description;
```

Full code looking like below which currently is ONLY pulling from the second result from *sports.yahoo.com/tennis/rss.xml*:

```
## Loop through results from mysql
try{
    #connection string
        // $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydatabase',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=mydatabase','myuser','mypass',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1");
    #call stored proc
        $q->execute();
    #get the rows into an array
        $result = $q->fetchAll();
        $newsStory[] = array();
        foreach($result as $r){
            $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
            $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
            # -> Setup XML
            $newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
        }

    # -----> Load News Stories
        for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

    # Source of Article Info-->
            $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

    # Actual News Article Info -->
            $title=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $desc=$newsStory[$i]->description;

    # Output Results ------------>      
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
            //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
            echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
            ##echo 'count '.count($result);
            echo '<hr>';
        }
} // try
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Example of a simple output from a single db result, which I am calling my hardcoding a result instead of dynamically using

```
$xmlUrl ="http://edge1.catalog.video.msn.com/videoByTag.aspx?tag=Fox%20Sports_NBA%20news&ns=MSNVideo_Top_Cat&mk=us&sd=-1&sf=ActiveStartDate&vs=0&ind=&ps=&rct=&ff=88&responseEncoding=rss&title=FOX%20Sports%20Video%20on%20MSN:%20NBA&template=foxsports&p=foxsports";
$ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
```

:
[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this block of code:

```
    $newsStory = array();
    foreach($result as $r){
        $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
        $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
        # -> Setup XML
        $newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
    }
```

Your previous code was declaring $newsStory as an array of arrays. Then it was overwriting that definition and turning $newsStory into a simple string.
It explains the behaviour you noticed: "currently is ONLY pulling from the second result".

And since you didn't tell us about any PHP errors, you probably didn't turn them on. Add these lines at the beginning of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // tells PHP to report all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // tells PHP to display all errors on the screen
```

Documentation: [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: thanks for that snippet. It is showing 19 now, which is accurate because the SQL query has 19 "rows". But, what I'm trying to do is have each 'row' append to $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink']; and each of the 19 of these results spit out. Following me?

Comment: Jocelyn, please view the example of a simple return from 1 row in the database above.

Comment: Maybe turn $xmlUrl into an array?

Comment: I found out what it's doing. Its taking the 19 results and returning ONLY the first 'item' from each of the 19 rss feeds with the description, link, title. How do I get it to show *every* item for *every* rss feed? I really appreciate your help Jocelyn